# IMG in A-Frame Asset Management System not loading

Tags: aframe

If I use the A-Frame Asset Management System I'm having problem getting the `img` assets to render. Example Glitch and code below. I *previously* had success with the A-Frame Asset Management System, and my old projects are still working, but for some reason, new projects using the exact same format don't. If I put the URL inline, it works fine, so the assets themselves are fine, but when piped through the asset management system, not so much.

https://asset-problem.glitch.me/

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Hello, WebVR! • A-Frame</title>
    <meta name="description" content="Hello, WebVR! • A-Frame">
    <script src="https://aframe.io/releases/0.8.2/aframe.min.js"></script>
  </head>


    <a-scene>

    <!--Assets-->
    <assets>

    <img id="sky" src="https://cdn.glitch.com/c96b441a-61dd-427b-86b9-ab2241e3eb22%2Ftwo_tone_sky.jpg?1538274492274">
    <img id="bust" src="https://cdn.glitch.com/c96b441a-61dd-427b-86b9-ab2241e3eb22%2Fbust.jpg?1538276649814">

    </assets>

    <!--Sky-->
    <a-sky src="#sky"></a-sky>

    <!--Box-->
    <a-box class="clickable" position="-2 0.5 -3" rotation="0 45 0" material="#ffccff" shadow></a-box>

    <!--bust-->
    <a-image src="bust" position=".5 2 -1.5" rotation="0 -25 0"></a-image>


    <!--Plane-->
    <a-plane position="0 0 -4" rotation="-90 0 0" width="10" height="10" color="#9999ff" shadow></a-plane>

    </a-scene>

    <!-- include the Glitch button to show what the webpage is about and
          to make it easier for folks to view source and remix -->
    <div class="glitchButton" style="position:fixed;top:20px;right:20px;"></div>
    <script src="https://button.glitch.me/button.js"></script>


</html>
```

Comment: Any errors in console? Do you see the images fetched on the networked panel?

Comment: Ugh, Dan Sinni got me sorted out. Somehow I was attempting to use <assets> instead of <a-assets>.

Comment: Excellent. Can you answer the question in StackOverflow for future reference?